# Janela WPF não ultrapassar a tela

Tags: c#, wpf

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
    System.Windows.Point ponto = PointToScreen(Mouse.GetPosition(this));

    JanelaAbrir.Left = ponto.X;
    JanelaAbrir.Top = ponto.Y;

    JanelaAbrir.ShowDialog();
```

Ele abre a Janela na posição do mouse, porém essa janela pode ultrapassar os limites do monitor, como posso fazer para ela não ultrapassar os limites?

Para ilustrar melhor segue uma imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ao abrir a janela ultrapassa a borda, limite da tela(monitor), impedindo que o usuário veja a janela completa, obrigando a arrastar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma hipótese é, nesse caso, as coordenadas do rato não definirem o canto superior esquerdo da janela mas o canto superior direito.
O mesmos se pode fazer caso a janela não caiba verticalmente, em vez de definirem o canto superior esquerdo definem o canto inferior esquerdo.
Caso as duas situações se verifiquem será considerado o canto inferior direito.

```
int x = coordenada x do rato;
int y = coordenada y do rato;
int maxX = largura da tela;
int maxY = altura da tela;
int largura = largura da janela;
int altura = altura da janela;

if(x + largura > maxX) JanelaAbrir.Left = x - Largura;
else JanelaAbrir.Left = x;
if(y + altura > maxY) JanelaAbrir.Top = y - altura;
else JanelaAbrir.Top = y;
```

Isto é válido se as dimensões da janela forem menores que a metade das dimensões da tela e que a origem das coordenadas está no canto superior esquerdo da tela.

Comment: Funciono, mais o menos, pois tem hora que abre, e as vezes a janela fica atrás, da principal, toda branca...

Comment: Isso é causado por outra coisa. Este código apenas define as coordenadas do canto superior esquerda da janela.

Comment: Beleza, descobri o erro, em vez usar `JanelaAbrir.Left`, tava usando `this.Left`, corrigi e não deu mais o erro. Obrigado!